# BizTalk configuration troubleshooting

Tags: config, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am trying to configure BTS 2016 3.12.774.0 against SQL Server v 17.9.1.  They are running on separate servers running Windows server 2016 64 bit OS.

The Enterprise Single Sign On database (SSODB) and the Business Rules Engine DB (BizTalkRuleEngineDB) get created but only to BRE is configured when I go into Biztalk Config.

I have had the servers rebooted but no change.

The Ent SSO Service does not exist in Services

User doing the install is in groups Biztalk Server Admin, Application Users, Server Operators and SSO Admin, Affiliate Admin all at the domain level.

Names of both servers are 13 characters.

Not sure what to look for in the configuration logs.  I have searched for the words Error, Fail, Exception but there are none.

A new attempt to configure gave the following error:

> Microsoft BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard ------------------------------ Failed to create the SQL database 'SSODB' on SQL Server 'servername10' (with SSO Administrator account 'SSO Administrators'). (SSO) For help, click: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/… ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: (0xC0002A21) An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database. (SSO) For help, click: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/… ------------------------------ An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database. See the event log (on computer 'servername10') for more details. (SSO)

Comment: "See the event log (on computer 'servername10') for more details" What does the Event Log say?

Comment: @Johns-305 Basically the same.  Here is what is strange.  It says it is trying to create the SSODB on the BTS Server NOT the SQL Server.  But I specified the SQL Server in the definition

[7:24:46 PM Info SSOServerCfg] (ssoconfigobj2.cpp:5164) Returning error description: <Exception Message="Failed to create the SQL database 'SSODB' on SQL Server 'BTSServerdb10' (with SSO Administrator account 'SSO Administrators')." Source="SSO" HelpID=""><Exception Message="(0xC0002A21) An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.&#xA;" Source="SSO" HelpID="">

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL Server v 17.9.1.  That version number is one for SSMS.

BizTalk Server 2016 does not support SQL Server 2017.  [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2016)

Please post the error text, either from the little red X or the error log.  There will always be an error.  BT Config will never silently fail.